# .height goes works only 1 time

Tags: jquery

I have all slides hidden at first and read into an array. Then I use forward and previous buttons to navigate thru the slides. Each one has its own description, inside a div. The slideshow itself works, and the description shows perfectly at every new slide as I navigate. but when I try to show the descriptions text's height, like this:

```
    $('.slide-desc').click(function () {
        $(this).text($('.slide-desc').height());
    });
```

it will return 0 in EVERY slide EXCEPT the first one in the array.
but all slide are actually loaded into that array cuz my slide show works.

This is how I turn all slides into an array:

```
    function getSlides() { 
        slidesArray = $('.slide').toArray();
        slidesArrayReversed = $('.slide').toArray().reverse();
    };
```

Why does it work only for the first?

More details:
You can see the script in action in http://purplerain.com.br/portfolio.html
and here you can see the whole script's code: http://purplerain.com.br/js/fullscreen-slideshow.js

It's just long to post here. As a warning... I tend to code using much more of a Finite State Machine mindset than an Object Oriented mindset.

thanks for the help ^^

Comment: Is the first slide visible and the others hidden ?

Comment: This might not be necessarily related, but inside your click function, `this` and `$('.slide-desc')` should be referring to the same object.

Comment: the first slide is also hidden by the time of page load.

When the page is first loaded I only have placeholder text in there, as an excuse to auto-load the slideshow. This is where you can see the script in action: http://purplerain.com.br/portfolio.html

it is not in english, but click the + button and the long description text will show. click it....  it changes. I jsut used $(this) because on some slides I have 3 paragraphs with the same .slide-desc class tag.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with your js, use `$(this)`

```
$('.slide-desc').click(function () {
    $(this).text($(this).height());
});
```

You could also try this plugin to get the height of any element in any state (hidden or visible)

https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.actual

Comment: well :/   like that, the click jsut doesn't work at all. I will have to check the plug in later too.   Thing is...  I don't think it's a matter of referencing or about the element being hidden, for 2 reasons...  a) when that code is called the element is visible, and b) it will always work for the first element in the array, just not all of the others.  So i'm GUESSING it is about the array somehow :/  I jsut dunno how to fix it